# Is there a difference between new List<T>() and new List<T>(0)

Tags: c#, .net, list, memory-management

Is there a difference between `new List<T>()` and `new List<T>(0)` ?

May be this is a *micro-optimization*, but the idea is to understund the difference in term of **memory allocation**.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,55

Comment: it is the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327712/c-sharp-generic-list-with-default-size-or-supply-one

Comment: The statements are essentially the same from a memory alloc standpoint

Comment: @EricJ. but the list doesn't actually allocate a 4-element array until you add the first item to the list; see Scott Chamberlain's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here is the actual source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646) (Some parts trimmed for brevity)

```
    static readonly T[]  _emptyArray = new T[0];  

    public List() {
        _items = _emptyArray;
    }

    public List(int capacity) {
        if (capacity < 0) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        if (capacity == 0)
            _items = _emptyArray;
        else
            _items = new T[capacity];
    }
```

As you can see calling `List()` and `List(0)` both just assign `_emptyArray` to `_items`. The code (in terms of memory footprint) are identical.